# Create multiple marker points on Google Maps In a Web Application from C# objects

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps, webforms

I've got a Web Application with C# code that creates a list of objects with their long and lat. I want to then create marker points on Google Maps for them using Javascript. I've currently got this code:

```
  var marker;
  for (var i = 0; i < ('<%= Buses.Count %>' - 1); i++) {
       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng('<%= Buses['i'].latitude %>', '<%= Buses['i'].longitude  %>'),
        map: map
       });
  }
```

Which does not work, I believe the error is with where I reference "i" to say which object in the list to use.

If I manually set a marker point without a for loop and change ['i'] to [0] it will place a marker fine. However, due to the number of items changing and reaching up to 100 I require using a for loop. I have tried removing the '' around i and this generates an error saying

> "i does not exist in the current context."

I have seen these posts:
[Add two marker points in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525869/add-two-marker-points-in-google-maps)

[Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

[Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

However, all of these are using locations inside of the JavaScript. My objects are contained within the C# code as a custom object defined as:

```
public static List<Bus> Buses = new List<Bus>();
```

This is my C# Code in full:
https://pastebin.com/2M1hWjnM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing a javascript for with data in code-behind/C#. It not works. 
First, you've to put the marks data on a javascript array. Then make your for without webforms tags <%%>

put something like this on your page code behind (C#)

```
public static string getBusesJson()
    {
        var buses = new List<Bus>();

        buses.Add(new Bus() {latitude = 10, longitude = 20 });
        buses.Add(new Bus() { latitude = 15, longitude = 30 });
        buses.Add(new Bus() { latitude = 5, longitude = 40 });

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(buses);

    }
```

put this on your aspx header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var points = <%= WebApplication3.WebForm1.getBusesJson()%>;

    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        //pass points[i].latitude and points[i].longitude to google maps
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Would you be able to show me what you mean by this? I can provide the C# code if needed.

Comment: Ok, looks again.

Comment: I had to tweak what you posted, but the main concept was still there and its now working. Thank you very much.